# Web App in Flaky Internet connection

Tags: reload, service-worker, cache-manifest, offlineapps, progressive-web-apps

Have PHP/mySQL/JS-JQuery based web site that records finish times for racers, then sends the time back to the server.  The server inserts the finish time in the db, Calculates the finish place based on a handicapping formula. Stores that and send the finish place back to the web page and it is updated on the screen.
It uses Jquery Ajax calls so the page doesn't get reloaded at all.
Everything works fine if the data connection is good.

If the data connection is bad my first version of this page would put a message up that the connection was bad.
Now I am trying to make it a bit smarter, so I have started with the HTML5 feature that tells the browser if it is on or offline(i realize this may not be the best way yet but it works for concept testing)
When a new finish time is recorded(or updated) and we are offline the JS just adds a class of notSent to the  tag of the finish time. The finish place and all of the finish places would normally come from the sever are greyed out indicating the data is no longer valid(until it can communicate with the server).

When the browser finds itself back online, A simple jQuery each loop on each notSent class starts re-sending the AJAX requests and if they all get completed it processes the return finish place information and display it as up to date.

It also disables all external links on the page when the browser is offline.  This keeps the user from losing the data entry page by accident by clicking a link that will give them a page not found button.

So my last issue, is the browsers reload and close buttons, if the user click these when it is offline they will lose the data entry screen and are out of luck until the connection comes back. 
Can I disable these functions as well?   A quick Stack-overflow search of this indicates it can be done but most answers give the old, *"you really shouldn't and if you think you need to you should rethink your design."* warning.

So rethinking my design I start learning about;

- HTML 5 local storage (decide I don't need it, since my data is stored already in a input box)
- App-cache Manifest for controlling the cache of the page so if reloaded in the browser off line if would get that cached version.  After much reading came to the conclusion that this could work on a static page but not mine where the data is updated all the time.  Then found that most browsers are deprecating this anyways.
- Service Workers seems to be the possible future for contorlling offline caching, but not all browsers support it, it is pretty cumbersome to learn and still very new.

Now I am stuck,  Leaning towards preventing browser reloads and defering learning service worker till more support and better examples for a dynamic content pages like mine.

Bottom line- am I missing something here?  Is there a easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) to sync between the client and server and use [Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) to awake a Service Worker when you regain connectivity. If Service Worker is not present in your browser, it can sync the next time your user open the browser.

You have a similar [example of deferred requests](https://serviceworke.rs/request-deferrer_demo.html) explained in the Service Worker Cookbook,